# *OpenIMSCore* How to install OpenIMSCore

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ims

I would like to install the OpenIMSCore on my virtualbox machine and I follow this instruction: [OpenIMSCore in a VM](http://www.openimscore.org/downloads-2/vm). I already downloaded the folders and extracted them but I dont know how to open them with the virtualbox.

This is a folder after I extracted the files:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use VirtualBox. To start this virtual-machine you have to use VMware Software, for example VMware Workstation Player.

Comment: hi, could you please explain me a litte bit more in details. I dont really get it

Comment: Virtual Machine on page OpenIMSCore is prepared only on VMware. VMware is the second next VirtualBox recovery environment for virtualization. If you want to run a virtual machine downloaded from the OpenIMSCore you have to use the VMware environment. After running VMware just select OPEN, indicate the folder location of a virtual machine from page OpenIMSCore and everything should work as expected

Comment: but after I import the project to VMware, do I need to setting anything else? because after importing then I open the browser and excute some functionality like CSCF or HSS, the browser is shown offline and not working